# Laravel - How to use/access session variables in a view?

Tags: php, laravel

I only find information on how to save a session variable which works like this: `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');`

But how can I access the session in a blade view?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `session()` helper to read the data:

```
{{ session('key') }}
```

Or:

```
{{ request()->session()->get('key') }}
```

If you want to store something, do this:

```
@php(session(['key' => 'value']))
```

Answer (score 4):

Its quite simple as core php,
you can use its facade in blade or a method like,

```
{{Session::get('key')}}
```

Or by method like,

```
{{ session()->get('key') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a session variable called $mySessionVar and inside you have key value pair information then you could use:

```
<p>
    @if(Session::has('$mySessionVar'))
        {{ Session::get('mySessionVar')['keyName'] }}
    @endif
</p>
```

And in case the value is an array (key/value pair) you could use:

```
@foreach(Session::get('mySessionVar')['keyName'] as $variableName)
    <span>{{ $variableName }} </span>
@endforeach
```